# How to download images from JSON and core data to display in tableView in Swift

Tags: json, swift, core-data, uiimage

Here i am downloading JSON data and saving it in core data for offline store. When displaying JSON data in tableView it works fine for me.
But when i am fetching JSON data from core data i am getting text but unable to display images in tableView why? 
Can anyone please help me in the below code

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

struct JsonData {

var nameS: String?
var picS: String?
var spouseS: String?

init(name: String, image: String, spouse: String) {

    self.nameS = name
    self.picS = image
    self.spouseS = spouse
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

var iteamsArray = [JsonData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    fetchData()
}

func downloadJsonwithImages() {

    let urlStr = "http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        guard let respData = data else {
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        do{
            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]

            let actors = jsonObj["actors"] as! [[String: Any]]

            for actor in actors {

                let name = actor["name"] as! String
                let pic = actor["image"] as! String
                let spouse = actor["spouse"] as! String

                self.iteamsArray.append(JsonData(name: name, image: pic, spouse: spouse))
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("catch error")
        }
    }).resume()

    self.saveCoreData()
}

func saveCoreData(){

    let urlStr = "http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        guard let respData = data else {
            return
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        do{
            let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: respData, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]

            let actors = jsonObj["actors"] as! [[String: Any]]
            for actor in actors {

                let name = actor["name"] as! String
                let pic = actor["image"] as! String
                let spouse = actor["spouse"] as! String

                let coreData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Actor", into: self.context) as! Actor
                coreData.name = name
                coreData.spouse = spouse

                //Converting NSString to NSData
                let picNSData = pic.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!
                //assigning NSData value to core data attribute
                coreData.image = picNSData as NSData
                print("core data saved images \(coreData.image!)")
            }
            try self.context.save()
        }
        catch {
            print("catch error")
        }
    }).resume()
}


func fetchData() {

    do {
        let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Actor> = Actor.fetchRequest()
        let actors = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        if actors.count > 0 {

            for actor in actors as [Actor] {

                let nameCore = actor.value(forKey: "name")
                let spouseCore = actor.value(forKey: "spouse")

                //here imageData contains nsdata
                let imageData = actor.value(forKey: "image")

                //converting NSData to String for append JsonData Struct
                let imageCore = String(describing: imageData)
                print("we r in fetch image.. \(imageCore)")

                self.iteamsArray.append(JsonData(name: nameCore as! String, image: imageCore , spouse: spouseCore as! String))
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        else {
            downloadJsonwithImages()
        }
    } catch { print(error) }
}


func loadImageFrom(URL url:String, forImage imageView:UIImageView) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {

        //when i run second time means its fetching from core data cell.picImageview.image != nil
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!)//fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
        }
    }
}

}

// MARK: - TableView

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return iteamsArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JsonCell", for: indexPath) as! JsonTableViewCell
    let aData = iteamsArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.labelName.text = aData.nameS
    cell.labelUsername.text = aData.spouseS


    if cell.picImageview.image == nil {

        self.loadImageFrom(URL: aData.picS!, forImage: cell.picImageview)
    }else {
        //what should i do to fetch from core data
        self.loadImageFrom(URL: aData.picS!, forImage: cell.picImageview)
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
}
```

Please help me to fetch images from core data to tableview.

Comment: Are you saving image url  or directly  image in CoreData.

Comment: make sure you are converting imageUrl to image .

Comment: @Malleswari in saveCoreData() func i have converted string to nsdata and in fetchData() i have converted nsdata to string

Comment: please help me i will give upVote for answer

Comment: Just save directly  Imageurl into coredata ,while feching data from Coredata use SDWebImage pod for getting image from imageUrl .

Comment: oh, sorry i don't know actually. can't we fetch JSON images directly from core data

Comment: you can fetch imageUrl ,but you can't assign imageUrl to imageview directly .

Comment: what i am saying is after fetch imageUrl from CoreData convert it to image Using SDWebImage and assign it to imageView

Comment: @Malleswari  no i have converted in this func loadImageFrom(URL url:String, forImage imageView:UIImageView).    but  while fetching got error in this line         let data = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!)//fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Use If let data = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: url)) {} statement

Comment: thanks for ur patience, but got the same error

Comment: You most likely get the error because the image url is empty in your persistence store or your weird conversion between String and NSData fails. Run your program in the debugger, both for when you save data and when you retrieve data.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson okay, yes i will do some modifications in NSString to NSData conversion.